# Strange Space on Web-page, CSS-Related

Tags: css

Link to web-page: http://cuttingedgehershey.mckennastudios.com/

So when you go there you see 5% of black space, and if you scroll down you'll see other random parts where that is also visible.

This is the code:
    .content {
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    height: 80%;
    width: 60%;
    }

and if I make it padding-top the black disappears but then there is padded space every where. How can I make my content 5% down on every page without an awkward spacing? I'm not really sure what's happening with this.

Comment: padding-top needs to go to your BODY css, not the .content class.  Or you can wrap your content in a container and add margin-top or padding-top to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making slide ID's and making a slide class and then when I added the padding to the slides themselves it fixed my issue. I love using inspect element as well but when I'm not quite sure where to go at times it's a little much.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the margin-top: 5% on your .content class, and add padding top: 5% to your body css.  That's one way to do it.

Comment: It removed it on every instance except the home page on load, but then my content is aligned at the top of the page still instead of 5% down...

I should also add if I completely remove the margin-top there's still some background leaking into my home slide of about 25 px.

Comment: you could then add the margin-top to your #sidebar and your div.content CSS... if those are the things you'd like to push down a bit.  What helps me a lot with this is using "inspect element" in chrome, and you can edit css / html on the fly to see what it will look like.  Good luck!

Comment: I ended up making slide ID's and making a slide class and then when I added the padding to the slides themselves it fixed my issue. I love using inspect element as well but when I'm not quite sure where to go at times it's a little much.